# Origin of "spick and span"

Tags: etymology, phrases

I recently described my room as being *spick and span* and I realized I had no idea what that really meant.

It occurred to me that it might stem from a derogatory term (*spick*), so I thought I'd ask here to make sure there wasn't some racist historical origin. What is its origin?

Comment: *Spick and span* means *clean like new*.  Wikipedia has some suggestions on the ethnic implications of [spic and span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spic) as a modern phrase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't come from a derogatory term.

It appears to be a combination of two terms that mean new.  Span came from Old Norse and spick came from Dutch.

> ORIGIN late 16th cent. (in the sense ‘brand new’): from spick and span new, emphatic extension of dialect span new, from Old Norse spán-nýr,
>   from spánn ‘chip’ + nýr ‘new’; spick influenced by Dutch
>   spiksplinternieuw, literally ‘splinter new.’
>   New Oxford American Dictionary - Mac Dictionary App

The derogatory term is much more recent.

> ORIGIN early 20th cent.: abbreviation of US slang spiggoty, in the same sense, of uncertain origin: perhaps an alteration of speak the in ‘no speak the English.’
>   New Oxford American Dictionary - Mac Dictionary App

Answer (score 5):

Here’s what ‘Brewer’s Dictionary of Phrase and Fable’ gives under ‘Spick and Span New’:

> Quite and entirely new. A spic is a spike or nail, and a span is a
>   chip. So that a spick and span ship is one in which every nail and
>   chip is new. The more common expression today is spick and span,
>   meaning all neat, clean, bright, and tidy.